# How listen for an update from a server?

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I'm building a page in flutter which needs validation from the server in order to proceed.

How do I set up a listener to have a block of code run when the sever validates at an unknown time?

Currently I have to hit a button to query the server manually to see if I have been validated, but I want to just have the sever shoot me a message when it's complete (and I need the app to be able to recogize it).

Comment: Read about web sockets ,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send any message from server to client without client request, you need to open a two-way interactive communication session between server and your flutter app. Just check out websocket